# Game's background leaving a trail or smudge trace when in motion

Tags: python, pygame, horizontal-scrolling

So I have been trying to implement a scrolling background in my game recently, however the game background when moved to the left as I move forward leaves a huge trail such as so:

[image]

The code is here down below:

```
#Game background
background = pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load('splash.jpg'), (WIDTH,HEIGHT))#background size being adjusted to fit a particular screen size
background_xpos = 0 #the x position of the background is at 0 of (0,0)
background_xpos2 = background.get_width() #obtains the width of the background at a certain coordinate 

def UpdateGame():    
    window.blit(background,(background_xpos,0))
    window.blit(background,(background_xpos,0))
    pg.display.update()

run = True  #while the game is running
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS) #determines the amount of frames per second
    background_xpos = background_xpos - 2
    background_xpos2 = background_xpos - 2

    if background_xpos < background.get_width() * -1:
        background_xpos = background.get_width()

    if background_xpos2 < background.get_width() * -1:
       background_xpos2 = background.get_width()
```

Comment: When you scroll-past the entire width of the background, what do you expect to happen?  Should it loop-around? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the screen before.

```
#Game background
background = pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load('splash.jpg'), (WIDTH,HEIGHT))#background size being adjusted to fit a particular screen size
background_xpos = 0 #the x position of the background is at 0 of (0,0)
background_xpos2 = background.get_width() #obtains the width of the background at a certain coordinate 

def UpdateGame():    
    window.blit(background,(background_xpos,0))
    window.blit(background,(background_xpos,0))
    pg.display.update()

run = True  #while the game is running
while run:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(FPS) #determines the amount of frames per second
    background_xpos = background_xpos - 2
    background_xpos2 = background_xpos - 2

    if background_xpos < background.get_width() * -1:
        background_xpos = background.get_width()

    if background_xpos2 < background.get_width() * -1:
       background_xpos2 = background.get_width()
```

Comment: Thank you, that stopped the trail from appearing, however the screen is now showing the background and then all black, repeatedly.

Comment: can you update the question with a picture of what you mean